# Trying to play with the annotation and bubble callout on mkmapview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview

I am developing an application in iphone which deals with maps. I have many annotations. I need different images to be loaded in the callout bubble.It mean user can edit the callout it may be image and He also type text on callout bubble .How can I give give multiple action on the callout bubble .
And most important think is that this annotation must drop on the map after clicking the save button. For Example I have two class (mapview And photoview),And in photoView i have three button (chooshphoto,takephoto,usephoto)when user take photo or browse for photo and he want use this photo.When he click on usephoto button the annotation must drop after that.And display onthe mapView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second half of your question isn't very clear but I'll try and answer the first.

The only real customisation you can apply to the callout view for an MKAnnotation is to set the Title, subtitle labels and the left/right calloutAccessoryViews. You can set the latter to images or callOutAccessoryViewIndicators, or another UIView but it can't be taller than 32 pixels.
[MKAnnontationView documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008207)

That's really about it I'm afraid. For anything more advanced than that, you'll have to create a custom implementation. [This](http://blog.asolutions.com/2010/09/building-custom-map-annotation-callouts-part-1/) blog post should be helpful, I plan on building something similar myself.

MKPinAnnontationView can be set to drop on the map as you describe so as long as you're happy with the Pin image for the annontation view itself, you can simply set it's `animatesDrop` property to YES and it will animate onto the map when it's added.

[MKPinAnnontationView documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPinAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008203)

EDIT: I think this is what you want;-

In your mapView controller, define a property to hold the object you want to animate.

```
@interface MyMapViewController {

    Photo *photoToAnimate;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) Photo *photoToAnimate;

@end
```

Then in your implementation file, add the following to `ViewDidAppear`

```
-(void)ViewDidAppear {
     ...
     if (photoToAnimate) {
         [mapView addAnnotation:photoToAnimate];
         self.photoToAnimate = nil; // reset it for the next time
     }
     ...
 }
```

Then in your PhotoViewController, simply set the property on the button press

```
-(void)usePhotoAction {
    ...
    mapViewController.photoToAnimate = photo;
    ...
 }
```

At least that's the really simple hacky way of what I was trying to describe in the comments. `ViewDidAppear` will fire when the MapView re-appears and it will add the pin to itself accordingly. If you need to add more than one pin, use an array to store them and iterate through the array.

There might be better patterns for this but in short, your MapView needs to get hold of the object you want to drop somehow and then not actually do anything with it until `ViewDidAppear` is called.

Comment: My second half is about the annotation only But it little bit complex .I am talking about animatesDrop property of pin I want this must drop after the click of button which is on the setting page not the same where map.The When user go on the setting page if he want to drop pin click on that button which on the setting not map .After clicking on the button when he came onthe map page he found the pin on current location user.

Comment: Right, if I'm understanding you correctly, the user cannot see the "settings page" at the same time as the map? So after pressing a button on the settings page, when the user returns to the map the pin should animate dropping in to place?

Comment: Yes you are right .There is one drop button the setting page When user click on that button only then pin drop on the current location .

Comment: Right, then you may need to pass the annotation to the mapView and have that handle adding it to the map when it becomes visible again. As soon as you call `[mapView addAnnotation:annotation]` it will perform the drop, so it may be happening whilst the mapView is still off screen.

Comment: I've explained what I meant. Whether that's a good way to do it I don't know (probably not). It's not terribly clean or futureproof but if the requirement is simple, should work.

Comment: can we drop pin on the current location And can store this current location in sqlite .If yes then how can we do .If you ?

Comment: I've never used sqllite and really that's a different question. To get the current location you need to use the CoreLocation framework. If you're happy with my answer on the annontation part, perhaps accept that and ask a new question?

Comment: Now i am going try your code .Your code is near to my question .But what is the My Object over here  that 's making confusion to me .Can you more explain me about the MyObject.

Comment: @deftangel can you explain what is Myobject over here

Comment: Right, sorry. I've changed the property name to make it read more clearly. MyObject was meant to be the photo object you want to add an annotation for. Does that make more sense now?

Comment: what is in the Photo class .is that It look like this photo.h @interface Photo : NSObject <MKAnnotation>
{
    UIImage *image;
    NSNumber *latitude;
    NSNumber *longitude;
}

Comment: Yes, the photo class should be whatever class you are using to store the photo.

Comment: No I am talking about the annotation class .Can you send me this making test app on the github link to under stand it in better way please.

Comment: @deftangel what is in to the  photo     mapViewController.photoToAnimate = photo;

Comment: @deftangel Where you said "can't be taller than 32 pixels", I looked at the docs and didn't see that limitation. Is it explicitly in the docs currently? (docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/index.html )